# CSS выборка определенных элементов

Tags: html, css, css3

Пример
https://jsbin.com/qicozaroxo/edit?html,css,output

Подскажите как выбрать элементы которые подсвечены желтым цветом.

**Самое главное условие** - у этих элементов не может быть добавлен класс (класс selected был добавлен для наглядности) и структура html тоже не должна быть изменена (то есть нельзя отдельные блоки оборачивать во всякие врапперы и прочее). 
неизмена
Блоки идут друг за другом.

Пробовал с nth-child и nth-of-type - но никак не могу подобрать формулу

Comment: где там желтый то?

Comment: Сорян, если не обновилось. Вообщем элементы с классом selected

Comment: .selected {
  background-color: yellow !important;
} - можно добавить у кого не отображается

Answer (score 0):

```css
.card {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 60px;
}

.card:nth-of-type(n) {
  background-color: red;
}

.card-row {
  float: left;
  height: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green !important;
}

.wrapper div .card:nth-child(3n+2) { /* и это */
  background-color: yellow !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div> <!-- это -->
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card selected"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card selected"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-row"></div>
    <div><!-- это -->
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card selected"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card selected"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-row"></div>
    <div><!-- это -->
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card selected"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card selected"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Могу предложить такое решение, просто оборачивай группу квадратов в div + формула 3n+2

Comment: Нет, структуру тоже не могу менять. Сейчас добавлю в условие задачи

Comment: Вряд ли такое возможно, кроме как если написать функцию чтобы  к 3n+2 добавляло 1 после каждого 7-ого  квадрата.